# What is the middle digit of $9^{99}$?

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, integers

Find the total number of digits and the digit in the middle of $9^{99}$, $\it{without}$ actually calculating any other digit of the number.

PS: according to defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm, the answer is $0$. The number reads $$ 29 512 665 430 652 752 148 753 480 226 197 736 314 359 272 517 \\ 043 832 886 063 884 637 676 943 433 478 020 332 709 411 004 889.\,$$

Comment: $9^{99}=(10-1)^{99}=\sum_{i=0}^{99}\binom{99}{i}(-10)^i$ i think this helps.

Comment: may be in this particular case. How about any power ? A general method if exists..For example $9^{9^9}$ (I did not check if number of digits is odd though..)?

Comment: for total number of digits u can do $[log_{10}9^{99}]+1=95$

where $[.]$ denotes greatest integer function

Comment: @ashi: yes, and that justifies asking for the $48^{\rm th}$ digit.

Comment: $9^{9^9}$ has $369,693,100$ digits, so there is no middle-digit.

Comment: @Peter: thanks for the comment!

Comment: The question inspired me to ask whether Graham's number has an odd or an even number of digits, probably this cannot be decided in practice.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this question could be answered without any electronic help.

Comment: @Peter: agree, maybe you are right, but is worth trying to answer it ...